# PHP artisan middleware error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm getting this error whenever I try any php artisan command:

> [ErrorException]   Missing argument 2 for
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router::middleware(), called in C:\x   d defined

Anyone know the solution?

Comment: check all user defined middleware  ? in kernel.php

Comment: Post your routes.php code here

Comment: @user2486 I do not have any user defined middleware.

Comment: @adamyi I still get the error even with just Auth::routes(); only in my routes/web.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you add some wrong routes to app/routes.php just like what I did. I add some temp route like this:

```
//user routes
Route::get('/login');
Route::post('/login');
Route::get('/reg');
Route::post('/reg');
```

And I got the same errors as you .

After I deleted this lines , all works fine now.

Wish can help you .

Comment: I do not have this case in my routes/web.php, i still get the error even with just Auth::routes(); in the file.